# Owl Carousel use a single jQuery script for 2 sections or more

Tags: jquery, carousel, owl-carousel

Could anyone know how to modify my jQuery script to have 3 items and 4 items on different page sections?
Theoretical at Services Section, I have 4 items and at Blog Section I have 3 items.

Now if I use this script my blog section have 4 items and these are distorted.
Could I use the variant with children selector? How to code it professionally?

```
$('.owl-carousel').owlCarousel({
    loop:true,
    responsiveClass:true,
    dots:true,
    responsive:{
        0:{
            items:1,
            nav: true,
            dots:true
        },
        600:{
            items:2,
            nav:true,
            dots:true
        },
        1000:{
            items:4,
            nav: true,
            loop:false,
            dots:true
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I've had to do this. Add class owl-3 or owl-4 to the respective carousel and initialise with this code instead.

```
/* Set up owl-3 and owl-4 */
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
  if (jQuery('.owl-4').length) {
  // https://owlcarousel2.github.io/OwlCarousel2/docs
  jQuery('.owl-4').owlCarousel({
    loop:true,
    margin:30,
    nav:true,
    navText:["",""],
    dots:false,
    responsive:{
      0:{
        items:1
      },
      576:{
        items:2
      },
      768:{
        items:3
      },
      1000:{
        items:4
      }
    }
  });
}
if (jQuery('.owl-3').length) {
  jQuery('.owl-3').owlCarousel({
    loop:true,
    margin:30,
    nav:true,
    navText : ["",""],
    dots:false,
    responsive:{
      0:{
        items:1
      },
      576:{
        items:2
      },
      992:{
        items:3
      }
    }
  });    
 }
}
```